# Can not delete Google-managed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform

I can not delete Google-managed SSL certificate - when I delete it it comes back. This certificate is not used by any other services.

I can delete other certificates and they are not coming back.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the one with "provisioning failed" ? Did you try troubleshooting it ? Here's [GCP's troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/troubleshooting#certificate-managed-status). If you're not successfull please provide more details.

Comment: Did you got the solution? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

What ended up working for me is to delete the certificate through the CLI instead of Cloud Console. After deleting the Ingress that was using the certificate, I ran the following command to delete the certificate:

`kubectl delete ManagedCertificate [CERTIFICATE-NAME]`

After doing this, the certificate stopped coming back.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this issue. I found in the docs that certs can only be deleted if

> SSL certificates can only be deleted when no other resources (for example, target HTTPS proxies) refer to them.

I suspect this is what is causing this issue but I am unable to confirm this. On the cert page itself https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/loadbalancing/advanced/sslCertificates/list it clearly says  `In use by: Not used`.

I think there is some issue with google cloud not cleaning up references somewhere, but I am unable to find where. I have confirmed that none of my target proxies are referring to the cert. @dharmik-chauhan and @kerem-yazar have either of you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue. However, when I attempted to delete through `kubectl delete ManagedCertificate [CERTIFICATE-NAME]` as previously suggested, it responded with a "certificate not found" error. I fixed this by running the following command(s):

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates list`
to get the name of the reappearing certificate.

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete [NAME]` to delete the reappearing certificate.

They stopped coming back after this.