# Google managed SSL Cert stuck, can´t delete

Tags: ssl, gcp-load-balancer

I had the same issue ([Can not delete Google-managed SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62237910/can-not-delete-google-managed-ssl-certificate/76874237#76874237))  while trying to delete the SSL certificates via CLI, then I tried deleting the certs in the GUI. Nothing works and the certs show up again in the provisioning state. Any Idea what could help?

Tried to delete via GUI and CLI, certs were reported as deleted. Few Minutes later they are back again